# How to simplify moving multiple items?

Tags: java, javafx

In the node I have a lot of rectangles and pictures. By clicking on the arrow button, they all have to move in the opposite direction. I have nowhere found ways to somehow merge all these elements into one or move a node with its children. Is the only way - is to change the position of each element separately?

Comment: Wrap them in a suitable `Parent`? Simply use a loop? What is a "knot"?

Comment: @fabian, What is a suitable parent? Is it correct from the point of view of proper programming to use cycles in such cases? Group root = new Group (); <--- here it is. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Cycles in a scene structure (i.e. being able to call `getParent` a certain number of times on a node and arriving at the original node) will result in a exception at best and will break your program with a `StackOverflowError` at worst. The best `Parent` to use depends on the way the nodes are positioned...

Comment: @fabian either i have bad english or java. I did not understand.: DDD This problem can be solved by a cycle, but not recommended? You could not explain more simply: is it possible or not to move the node itself?

Comment: "move a knot with its children" I think you mean node. If so please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53904759/edit)

Comment: @c0der you're right! done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google still helped me find the answer to this question.

> There is no merging mechanism for all members of the same group. You
>   can use only one group / container to store all your items.

it only remains to use something like that

```
for(Node node:vBox.getChildren()) {
    node.setDisable(true);
}
```